# Searching multiple worksheets from an excel 2007 function

Tags: excel, vba

I have worksheets A, B and C. Worksheet A contains a column with dates. B and C each contain two columns: one with a date and one with a value. For example

worksheet A:

```
     A           B
1    2001-01-01  ---
2    2001-01-02  ---
```

worksheet B:

```
     A           B
1    2001-01-01  1
```

worksheet C:

```
     A           B
1    2001-01-02  2
```

I'd like to have a function `=Search(W, date)` that when run from worksheet `A` returns a value assigned to `date` in worksheet `W`. For example `Search(C, "2001-01-02")=2`.

This is an abstract version of searching for currency rates at given dates: multiple worksheets contain rates for currencies, so when we search, we know what worksheet (currency) to pick.

How to define such a function? I tried passing parameters to a custom macro, but excel keeps giving me cryptic errors. It's seems easy to use a macro that uses the selected cell as a source, but a function would be better.

EDIT: my attempt, doesn't work

```
Function FindRate()
    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rate As String
    Dim Src As Range
    Dim Found As Boolean

    MsgBox sheet_name
    Rate = "Not found "
    Set Src = Application.ActiveCell
    FindString = "2006-12-19"
    Sheets("cur CHF").Activate
    Found = False
    For Each c In [A1:C2000]
        If c.Value = FindString Then
            Rate = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Found = True
            Exit For
        End If
        Next

    MsgBox Rate
    'FindRate = Rate
End Function



Function Rate(cname As String)
    Dim sheet_name As String
    Dim c2s As New Collection

    c2s.Add "cur worksheet name", "cur"

    sheet_name = c2s.Item(cname)
    Call FindRate(sheet_name)

End Function
```

Comment: It always helps to show your existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are really doing is a lookup. There is a `VLOOKUP` function built into Excel that will do exactly what you want. The syntax is

```
VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])
```

This will look up the value `lookup_value` in the table `table_array`. It will find an exact match in the first column if `range_lookup` is false, otherwise it will find the closest value (faster, but data must be sorted).

It will return the value in the `col_index_num` column.

In your case, if you want the value from sheet B corresponding to "2012-01-01", you would do

```
=VLOOKUP("2012-01-01", Sheet2!A2:B1000, 2, false)
```

You may have to mess around with converting the date string into a date value, etc. If you had added the values on `Sheet2` as dates, you would want to use

```
=VLOOKUP(DATEVALUE("2012-01-01"), Sheet2!A2:B1000, 2, false)
```

since that function correctly converts the *string* `"2012-01-01"` to something Excel recognizes as a `DATE`.

Now if you don't know *a priori* which sheet you will need to access (because that's a variable), you may have to write yourself a VBA function:

```
Function myLookup(value, curr)
Dim dval As Long, luTable As Range, s As Worksheet, c As Range

' if user types date as string, convert it to date first...
If VarType(value) = vbString Then
  dval = DateValue(value)  ' this doesn't work if dval hasn't been declared as `long`!
Else
  dval = value
End If

' see if `curr` is the name of a defined range; if so, use it
On Error GoTo notArange
' if the next line doesn't generate an error, then the named range exists:
Set luTable = Range(curr)
' so let's use it...
GoTo evaluateFunction

notArange:
' If we got here, "curr" wasn't the name of a range... it must be the name of a sheet
' first, tell VBA that we're done handling the last error:
Resume here
here:
On Error GoTo noSheet
Set s = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(curr)

Dim firstCell As Range, lastCell As Range
Set firstCell = s.Range("a1")
Set lastCell = s.Range("b1").End(xlDown) ' assuming data in columns A and B, and contiguous
Set luTable = Range(firstCell, lastCell)

evaluateFunction:
myLookup = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(dval, luTable, 2, False)
Exit Function

noSheet:
' get here if currency not found as either sheet or range --> return an error message
myLookup = curr & " not found!"

End Function
```

This has been tested on a small sample, and it worked. A few things to note:

You can name the range where the conversion is kept ("euro", "dinar", "yen", ...) instead of keeping each on a separate sheet. You can then pass the name of the range (make it the same as the name of the currency for convenience) as a parameter to your function, and access it with `Range(currency)`. This also gets around the problem of "hard-wiring" the size of the range

The function will check for the existence of a named range, and use it if it exists. If it doesn't, it will look for a sheet with the correct name

If you use an "invalid currency name", this will be reflected in the return value (so `myLookup("01-01-2012", "Florins")` will return `"Florins not found!"`

Instead of assuming a lookup table of a certain length, I determine the size of the table dynamically, using the `End(xlDown)` construct

I allow date to be passed in as a `String`, or as a `DATEVALUE`. The function notices the string and converts it

Right now I am setting the `range_lookup` parameter to `False`. This means that there must be an exact match, and values that are not present will generate errors. If you prefer to return "the best match", then you set the parameter to `True`. Now the risk is that you will return garbage when the date requested is outside of your limits. You could solve this by setting the first and last value of the exchange rate column to "no valid data". When the lookup function returns, it will show this value.

Comment: Can you please modify your 'myLookup' function so it works in Excel? I'm trying to make it work, but excel errors aren't helpful. For example, it seems that you need to call Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup, instead of Application.VLookup.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple FindCell function I use a lot is simply extends Excels search function but from what you have got should suit fine.  It returns a range however it is simple enough to get the value from the return range.  I use it as follows (with comments added for your sake):

```
Function FindCell(SearchRange As Range, SearchText As Variant, OffsetDown As Integer, OffsetRight As Integer) As Range

    'Do a normal search range call using the passed in range and text.
    'First try looking formula
    Set FindCell = SearchRange.Find(What:=SearchText, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        MatchCase:=True, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Offset(OffsetDown, OffsetRight)

    'If nothing is found then look in values
    If FindCell Is Nothing Then
            Set FindCell = SearchRange.Find(What:=SearchText, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValue, _
            MatchCase:=True, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Offset(OffsetDown, OffsetRight)
    End If
End Function
```

This can be used a function for the rate (you could of course combine the two functions but I use FindCell for many applications so have kept it seperate):

```
Function GetRate(sWorksheetName As String, theDate As Date) As Double
    Dim returnRange As Range

    'Call the FindCell function specifying the range to search (column A), and the date and then offset one cell to the right for the value
    Set returnRange = FindCell(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sWorksheetName).Columns("A:A"), sDate, 0, 1)

    'Check if we've found something. If its Nothing then we haven't
    If Not returnRange Is Nothing Then GetRate = returnRange.Value
End Function
```

You can test it in a Sub like so:

```
Sub Test()
    MsgBox "Value is " & GetRate("Sheet2", "2001-01-01")
End Sub
```

By accepting the GetRate as a date type it shouldn't matter what format the date is in the worksheet.

Comment: In GetRate: s/sDate/theDate. Works :)

Comment: It doesn't work when used directly from excel: `=GetRate(...,...)` return VALUE error.

Comment: If you are just wanting to use this in a worksheet without further manipulation within VBA then it would be simplest to use the plain `VLOOKUP` worksheet function as per @Floris' suggestion, no need for VBA at all.  You can use the `VLOOKUP` function from different worksheets.

Comment: I know, but I'd like to wrap it in a helper function, so that I only have to call `=Rate(worksheet, date)` instead of the whole invocation.

Comment: Ok, well @Floris or my code will work from the worksheet. If you change `Function GetRate(sWorksheetName As String, theDate As Date) As Double` to `Function GetRate(sWorksheetName As String, theDate As String) As Double` mine will be good. However @Floris' VLookup is much more compact and simple for this use.